# Accessing clipboard in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, clipboard, electron

I would like to monitor whether the user has copied something to the clipboard while using another application and then save what he or she has copied in my nodejs (electron) application. How could I do this?

As an example:
The user uses his/her browser and selects a URI and then copies the URL to the clipboard. I then want to copy the selected URL from the browser window and use it in my nodejs application.

I am using nodejs with electron on OSX.

Comment: do you solemnly swear that you are up to no good?

Comment: Haha! I know it reads dangerous, but I am really just trying to write a tool which, instead of "copy text, switch to application, paste text", just notices the copy to clipboard and then pastes it into the app automatically while in this mode. I guess this is also reason this is being downvoted?

Comment: Seems so, i was waiting where this was going. What you want, and assuming you want this for yourself, is probably to create a browser extension, though I have no experience in that area. Wait what the others have to say

Comment: The application I have in mind is not only applicable to browsers, so a browser extension won't work. If people refuse to answer this here I understand. If anyone can point me to some books I can gladly read this up myself. On the other hand, features like these are not so uncommon, where the clipboard is monitored, for example, which would be enough for my purposes.

Comment: The down votes are probably because this is a very broad question, which doesn't meet the how-to-ask guidelines.

Comment: Ok, I changed the topic to be more specifically about accessing the clipboard with nodejs, which would help me out. This is more specific, I hope and maybe also less susceptible to malicious thinking people than my previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron exposes a (partly experimental) [clipboard API](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/clipboard/#clipboard) that should serve your needs.

Strangely, there seems to be no callback method available to react on new content, you may have to keep polling [`clipboard.read`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/clipboard#clipboardreadformat-experimental) and diff its content.